# Trying to use cmsImport to import to a MultipleTextstring from a comma delimited string

Tags: c#, umbraco

I', using cms import to improt data, its saving to a item object which consists of a name, aliases, and some others. the main issue (only) is the aliases, an item "hoover" may have aliases "vacuum" "vacuum cleaner", these are being imported as "vauum, vacuum cleaner" but aren't being correctly mapped to the MultipleTextstring

i've tried various things in custom mapping, returning the object.ToList() storing it as a seperate var of List and returning that , my final code below, is based off how it seems to be stored in the db (double space to seperate items) anyone got any ideas of what's wrong

```
[FieldProvider(Priority = FieldProviderPrio.High, PropertyEditorAlias = "Umbraco.MultipleTextstring")]
  public class RepeatableStringFieldProvider : IFieldProvider
  {
    public object Parse(object value, PropertyInfo property, FieldProviderOptions fieldProviderOptions)
    {
      if (property.PropertyAlias.Equals("aliases", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        value = string.Join("  ", value.AsString().Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()));
      }
      return value;
    }
  }
```

umbraco to store the MultipleTextstring as a list of aliases instead of just having one alias "vacuum vacuum cleaner"

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve, the "double space" mentioned was actually \r\n just replace the .Join method with \r\n as below

```
public object Parse(object value, PropertyInfo property, FieldProviderOptions fieldProviderOptions)
    {
      if (property.PropertyAlias.Equals("aliases", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        value = string.Join("\r\n", value.AsString().Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()));
      }
      return value;
    }
```